# How to make Eclipse prompt me for command line arguments

Tags: eclipse

I know I can configure command line arguments in the Run configuration but I want to run a java file multiple times with different command line arguments. It's a pain to change the Run Configuration every time.

Is there a way I can make Eclipse prompt me for command line arguments every time I run the program?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Add `string_prompt` as a `Program Argument` in the `Run` configuration.

```
 ${string_prompt}
```

There are also a `file_prompt` and a `folder_prompt` if you want specifically files\folders.

These are available through the `Variables` button on the `(x)= Arguments` tab of the Run Configuration dialog.

Answer (score 69):

This is an old question, but since I really don't see this extra info anywhere else

You can also type `${string_prompt:My Prompt Text:Default Value}`

And that will pop up a window asking '*Please input a value for My Prompt Text*' and then with a default value of '*Default Value*'.

Answer (score 19):

In addition you can add a string to the prompt by using ${string_prompt:My Prompt Text} which will show the dialog box with 'Please input a value for My Prompt Text'.