# Best way to use command line args for file types and operations

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm working on a small utility class that originally was going to read in one of four file types, which I had working.  Then I found out that after I know which type of file I"m dealing with, I had to know which operation was to be performed, so the obvious choice was to use two arguments.  The problem is I haven't worked with command line args much and I've never had to do multiple args on the command line.

So my questions are: is there some sample code to look at or do I just hack out some procedural code that specifically looks for something at args[0] and then at ags[1]?

Also, I wanted to know how to set the args values when running it under Eclipse so I don't pass anything in? Like when args is null because I'm not running it on the command line. So I hard code some values in the program itself under an else condition as in:

```
if(args.length() > 1){
}
else{
//Sets args here.
}
```

Thanks,
James

Comment: `args` is never going to be `null` when the JVM invokes your `main` method -- "worst case" is an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many Java libraries that offer command line handling, see [SO:Java library for parsing command-line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters). You scenario you described however seems arguably simple enough to just use `args` directly.

Note that `args` is an array, therefore `length` is not a method: `args.length > 1` .. (no brackets)

In order to set command line arguments in Eclipse have a look at [SO:How to make Eclipse prompt me for command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313270/how-to-make-eclipse-prompt-me-for-command-line-arguments).

Comment: Yes, I'll just go the simple route.  The complicated part is in the utility itself so I don't want to waste time on this piece.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(args.length > 1){
   // you can get the values for args[0] and args[1] here
}
else{
//Sets args here.
}
```

Commandline args can be set in eclipse under the run configurations. Right click on the class, select "run configurations" under "run" menu.

[image]

In the configurations window, create a new configuration under "Java Application" and you can set the command line args in the "program arguments" section

[image]