# Make VS2010 prompt me for command line arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, command-line, command-line-arguments

Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313270/how-to-make-eclipse-prompt-me-for-command-line-arguments) is there a way to make Visual Studio 2010 prompt me for command line arguments every time before launching? For one of my projects this would be nice since the arguments need to change on various runs, and it would be easier to do than to keep editing the properties of the project.

Comment: Before launching, or before opening a project or solution?

Comment: It would be right before launching, a la the question I linked. VS2010 doesn't have anything like Eclipse did so I'll need to bootstrap it myself.

Comment: I went ahead and posted it as a suggestion for VS: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2427918-option-to-force-visual-studio-to-prompt-for-startu#comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any way of getting Visual Studio itself to prompt for arguments - but you could create a small and simple app which prompted for the appropriate values in Windows Forms, then just invoked the `Main` method of the "real" project... or even launched it as a separate process.

This would have the additional benefit of making it easier to use in terms of getting the right arguments, I'd imagine.

Comment: After digging around in documentation it really has started to look like I'll need to make a bootstrap myself. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking a hidden feature :\ As always thanks for your fantastic input Jon!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in your Main:

```
if (args.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please provide an argument.");
    string strArg = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I knew I could do that or write a basic WPF or Form dialog, but I wanted to make sure VS2010 didn't have something like Eclipse did. But according to many resources such a feature does not exist in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running your project executable via External Tools, which can prompt for arguments.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this application, is there documentation or a crash course article on it somewhere? My Google-fu didn't turn up anything great.

Comment: Its part of Visual Studio - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9814d200.aspx