# Fuzz testing in Eclipse? Rule based fuzzer in 'Run As..."

Tags: eclipse, debugging, variables, testing, fuzzing

Does anyone know of a way to create fuzz testers within Eclipses 'Run' or 'Debug' tool?

I'm thinking of running some Java programs with fuzz arguments but want the best/cleanest way to generate the input within Eclipse.  Do I do this with the 'Variables' option?

If there is no way to do this within Eclipse, I may have to resort to the commandline, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [${string_prompt} variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313270/how-to-make-eclipse-prompt-me-for-command-line-arguments) in program arguments for your app launch configuration in Eclipse.

Though a better way would be to create an automated driver that will launch your program and check the output. You can use parametrized test with JUnit or TestNG or write a simple wrapper Java application.

Comment: ${String_prompt} variable would prompt me for input, correct?  That's a start but I'd like something which fuzzes the input... runs 100's or 1000's of inputs (given some constraints on the string)  ie {run the program with all prime numbers up to X}

Comment: Could this be a start? http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_core_variables_dynamicVariables.html

Comment: Sure, you can create your own Eclipse plugin that would contribute your custom variable. But any given launch configuration still going to launch your application once. To address that, see a second part of my answer.