# Run java program from Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, button, console

I have written a code in JAVA in Eclipse Indigo. I want to run that program from the console which is inside the eclipse (i.e. without using the RUN button). Because I want pass arguments which vary all the time and it is very tedious to set arguments from 'Run Configurations'.
Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You can pass arguments in the _running_ program from console. So you can run the program in a normal way.

Comment: I clicked on the RUN button, then it showing "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at MyProgram.main(MyProgram.java:13)
" I want to write ' java MyProgram arg0 arg1 ' to run program..rather then hitting RUN button

Answer (score 0):

You could create a configuration file pass that as your only variable in the "run configurations" then parse accordingly. Or you could prompt the user to type in the configurations each time you run the program. You may need to re-think how you are developing this code to accommodate for such variations.

Answer (score 0):

Add string_prompt as a Program Argument in the Run configuration.

${string_prompt}
There are also a file_prompt and a folder_prompt if you want specifically files\folders.

These are available through the Variables button on the (x)= Arguments tab of the Run Configuration dialog.

Ref : [How to make Eclipse prompt me for command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313270)