# Eclipse plug-in/view for quick-editing the command line arguments

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins, command-line, ide

In Eclipse, I can get to my main class' command-line arguments using `Run | Run Configuration | Arguments` - but this is not satisfactory for me. I want to be able to:

- Always see what the currently-set arguments are.
- Be able to edit them quickly, without having to open any menus.

The least I would like would be a view I could put next to the Console, History, Search etc. A better alternative would be some editable bar with the command-line arguments, stuck onto somewhere.

Is such a feature implemented? Maybe as a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of quick-editing, we can get Eclipse to prompt us for the command-line arguments. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313292/1593077).