# Set version with versions-maven-plugin in interactive mode with M2Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, versions-maven-plugin

I want to change the version of my multi module project with [`versions-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and goal [`versions:set`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) in Eclipse. I use [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

I can set the new version with `-DnewVersion=0.0.2-SNAPTSHOT` in the launch configuration and it works fine. But I want to use the interactive mode.

If I don't set `-DnewVersion=0.0.2-SNAPTSHOT` in launch configuration, I get following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.2:set (default-cli) on project test-parent: You must specify the new version, either by using the newVersion property (that is -DnewVersion=... on the command line) or run in interactive mode -> [Help 1]
```

[Maven Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Simple_Values) says:

> - **interactiveMode**: `true` if Maven should attempt to interact with the user for input, `false` if not. Defaults to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an interactive mode with Eclipse Run as > Maven Build.. configuration.

I would suggest to use the console for Maven builds which is more reliable and easier to handle.

If you don't want to leave your IDE, you can run a [Terminal](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) (which comes by default with the latest versions) via right click > Show In > Terminal or install a plugin like the [EasyShell](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell), both options will provide your a console already having as working directory your Maven project.

Comment: Why can't you have an interactive mode? Under the runc configuration, there is an option in "common" to allocate a console, which says it's necessary for for input.

Answer (score 12):

I found a work-around, see [How to make Eclipse prompt me for command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313292/5277820).

I have to define system property like this

```
-DnewVersion=${string_prompt:new version}
```

and after starting the launch configuration in Eclipse, I get a dialog to enter the new version. Then `versions-maven-plugin` uses the version from dialog.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works like a charm. Thanks for sharing!